# How to maintain semantic-ui?

Tags: npm, semantic-ui

I installed `semantic` according to the document:

```
npm install semantic-ui --save
cd semantic/
gulp build
```

If I customised the variables how can I maintain them? For example, if I `npm update semantic` some day, my change would be gone by the `semantic` upgrade.

How do you guys maintain semantic-ui in your projects?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a copy of your files outside semantic and write a gulp task to move it. 
Every time you update semantic, you can just run this task again, and then run a gulp build inside semantic.